# Mouse wheel suddenly scrolls 7 times faster than usual

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, mouse, scrolling

I'm using a Windows XP image in VirtualBox.

Then my scroll wheel suddenly began scrolling 21 lines at each tick instead of the usual 3. Why it does this and how can I reset it? It's very annoying and currently the only way to resolve it is rebooting the image...

I searched the web but found nothing relevant.

I don't know what hidden key combination I pressed and I'm also not sure whether its a VirtualBox glitch.

Answer (score 1):

Go to The Control Panel and click on "mouse", click the wheel tab, and change it back to 3.

That should do the trick...

[image]

Comment: It's already 3. But it has a weird 7× multiplier on it. So if I set to 1 it scroll 7 lines at each tick.

Comment: Do you have third party software installed for your mouse?

Comment: None. Though I use Virtualbox mouse integration disabling it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: Did you install the guest extensions?

Comment: Yes. I usually use it full screen.

Comment: What sort of mouse are you using?